# delayed_job not working on paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, delayed-job

I have this simply method that check against a URL existence and if not present try to create the photo object.

```
 def create_profile_photo(user_id,image_url)
   if Photo.find_by_external_url(image_url).blank?
     profile_photo = Photo.new
     profile_photo.user_id = user_id
     profile_photo.picture_from_url(image_url)
     profile_photo.save
   end   
 end

# Photo.rb
def picture_from_url(url)
  self.external_url = url
  self.attachment = URI.parse(clean_url)
end
```

It does work. But when I try to launch the method using `delayed_job` It does not work.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :085 > MyClass.new.delay.create_profile_photo(347,'http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png')
(0.4ms)  COMMIT
 => #<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job id: 42, priority: 0, attempts: 0, handler: "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::ProfileableMethod\nobject:...", last_error: nil, run_at: "2012-12-08 21:40:06", locked_at: nil, failed_at: nil, locked_by: nil, queue: nil, created_at: "2012-12-08 21:40:06", updated_at: "2012-12-08 21:40:06"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :085 > Photo.count
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "photos" 
=> 0
```

Any idea?

Comment: I gave up on DJ because of this kind of issue. Out of interest, can you get it to load if you restart the daemon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Of course there's no `Photo` instance in the `photos` table.**  According to your console, all you did was queue the job up.

Unless you have a DJ worker running, you can't expect the DJ queue to be processed. If the DJ queue isn't processed, you can't expect queued jobs to run. If the queued job hasn't been run, you can't expect `photos` to have any new records.

Run the command below and you'll see the job still queued up waiting to be run.

```
Delayed::Job.find(42)
```

In development, run the following to start a DJ daemon.

```
script/delayed_job
```

And finally, as @simonmorley suggested, make sure you kill and restart the daemon between code changes in order for the jobs to be processed by an up-to-date version of your application.